# Convert list of dicts into a unique dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
[
  {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'},
  {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'},
  {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}
]
```

I want:

```
{
  1: [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}
  ],
  2: [
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}
  ]
}
```

This code does this:

```
organized = {d['id']:[] for d in data}
[organized[d['id']].append(d) for d in data]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Why is this not a Pythonic way?  I feel like two line solution is pretty legit solution for python.

Comment: the problem is that it does two iterations over data, when just one is required

Comment: The other problem is that it's using list comprehensions for side-effects, which is distinctly anti-Pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in data:
    d[x['id']].append(x)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}], 2: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *groupby.itertools* we can create this *dicitonary*

```
from itertools import groupby
lista = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}]

d = {}
for k, g in groupby(sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x['id']), key=lambda x: x['id']):
    d[k] = list(g)
# {1: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}], 2: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}]}
```

or using *dictionary comprehension*

```
d = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x['id']), key=lambda x: x['id'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a 2-pass O(*n*) solution if you are, as here, working with an in-memory object. The main issue with your code is you are misusing the list comprehension.

A list comprehension should be used to *construct* a new list, not to process an in-place function or method in a loop. Taking your example, your logic will create a list which looks like:

```
[None, None, None, ..., None]
```

The *side-effect* of the comprehension means that `organized` values have items appended to them as required. Instead, you can rewrite using a simple `for` loop:

```
organized = {d['id']: [] for d in data}

for d in data:
    organized[d['id']].append(d)
```

Your logic can be made more efficient by *not* adding keys via an initial iteration. This common problem is resolved by [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), as in [@Austin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679753/9209546). This solution gives an empty list for any key which does not exist:

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    res[d['i']].append(d)

print(res)

defaultdict(list,
            {1: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}],
             2: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}]})
```

Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, there's usually no need to convert this back to a regular dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

[Austin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52679753/5491375) answer is better, but here method just using `dict`s

```
In [175]: data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}]

In [176]: organised = {}

In [177]: for d in data:
     ...:     if d['id'] in organised:
     ...:         organised[d['id']].append(d)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         organised[d['id']] = [d]
     ...:

In [178]: organised
Out[178]:
{1: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'gesiel'}],
 2: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar'}]}
```